# How to implement moving of the viewport of the FabricJS canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have a FabricJS canvas, which I want to work in the following way:

1. The user zooms in.
2. The user then moves the viewport (visible area) by pressing left, right, top, down buttons.

Each of the buttons calls the `moveViewPort` method:

```
<button
    type="button"
    onclick="moveViewPort(-1, 0);"
    class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
<button
    type="button"
    onclick="moveViewPort(1, 0);"
    class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
<button
    type="button"
    onclick="moveViewPort(0, -1);"
    class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
<button
    type="button"
    onclick="moveViewPort(0, 1);"
    class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

`moveViewPort` is defined as

```
function moveViewPort(deltax, deltay) {
    var canvas = window._canvas;
    canvas.absolutePan({
       x: canvas.width/2 + deltax,
       y: canvas.height/2 + deltay});
}
```

`canvas` is initialized in the HTML page:

```
<script>
    var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            top : 100,
            left : 100,
            width : 60,
            height : 70,
            fill : 'red'
        });

    canvas.add(rect);
    canvas.isDrawingMode = false;

    [...]
</script>
```

But it doesn't work as expected as shown in this [video](https://youtu.be/cD_8Pzo-6FI):

1. movement to the right doesn't work (the viewport moves only once, you cannot move to the right all the way),
2. same with movement to the top and bottom.

What is the right way to move the viewport of a FabricJS canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to increment the panning point, not change it every time with `deltax` and `deltay`. Check the snippet for an idea to manage it.

```js
var pos = {x:0, y:0}
function moveViewPort(deltax, deltay) {
var canvas = window._canvas;
pos.x += deltax;
pos.y += deltay;
canvas.absolutePan({
   x: pos.x,
   y: pos.y});
}

var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        top : 10,
        left : 10,
        width : 20,
        height : 30,
        fill : 'red'
    });

canvas.add(rect);
canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
canvas.setZoom(2);
```

```html
<button
type="button"
onclick="moveViewPort(-1, 0);"
class="btn btn-default">
LEFT
</button>
<button
type="button"
onclick="moveViewPort(1, 0);"
class="btn btn-default">
RIGHT
</button>
<button
type="button"
onclick="moveViewPort(0, -1);"
class="btn btn-default">
UP
</button>
<button
type="button"
onclick="moveViewPort(0, 1);"
class="btn btn-default">
DOWN
</button>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js" ></script>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=200 style="height:500px;width:500px;"></canvas>
```